# How to rotate WindRose plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, windrose, rose-plot

How can I rotate the Windrose plot and move the legend to avoid overlaying with the figure?

East should be on the opposite side.

Code and figure are below.

```
from windrose import WindroseAxes

ax = WindroseAxes.from_ax()
ax.bar(wind_almaty_angle.angle,wind_almaty_angle.rate, normed=True, bins=np.arange(0, 6, 1), cmap=cm.hot)
ax.set_legend(fontsize=12,loc='upper right')
ax.set_xticklabels(['N', 'NE', 'E', 'SE' , 'S', 'SW','W', 'NW'],fontsize=14)
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
plt.show()
```

[image: Python windrose output]

Comment: Did you notice a bug in the direction tags? https://github.com/python-windrose/windrose/issues/151

Answer (score -1):

just remove

```
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
```

or put another direction.